# Can't scrape breweries' names from a website using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script to collect the breweries' names from this [website](https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/) using the requests module, but when I execute the script, it ends up getting nothing. I looked for the title in the page source and also in any undocumented APIs that are usually found through dev tools, but no luck.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select(".company-content > h3[itemprop='name']"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.brewersassociation.org/wp-content/themes/ba2019/json-store/breweries/breweries.json'

data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('BillingAddress').apply(pd.Series, dtype=object)], axis=1)
df.pop('attributes')

# print sample data, total length should be 26802 breweries:
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Id | Name | Parent | Phone | Website | Brewery_Type__c | Is_Craft_Brewery__c | Voting_Member__c | Membership_Record_Item__c | Membership_Record_Paid_Through_Date__c | Membership_Record_Status__c | Account_Badges__c | city | country | countryCode | geocodeAccuracy | latitude | longitude | postalCode | state | stateCode | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0014x000012jyoHAAQ | Brewery in Planning - Monterrey |  | (811) 244-8078 |  | Brewery In Planning | False | False |  |  |  |  | Monterrey | Mexico | MX | Block | 25.6444 | -100.275 | 64850 |  |  | Tucan 362 |
| 0014x000012jyoJAAQ | Sekinoichi-shuzo Co.,Ltd/Iwai Brewery |  | +81-191-21-1144 | [www.sekinoichi.co.jp](http://www.sekinoichi.co.jp) | Brewpub | False | False |  |  |  |  | Ichinoseki-city | Japan | JP | Address | 38.9314 | 141.132 | 021-0885 |  |  | 5-42 Tamuracho |
| 0014x000012jyoKAAQ | Selby (Middleborough) Brewery Ltd |  | 01757 702826 |  |  | False | False |  |  |  |  | Selby | United Kingdom | GB | Block | 53.7871 | -1.07141 | YO8 3LL |  |  | 131 Milgate |
| 0014x000012jyoLAAQ | SENDERO BREWING COMPANY |  |  | [www.senderobrewing.com](http://www.senderobrewing.com) | Brewery In Planning | False | False | Brewery Membership | 2019-10-31 | Expired |  | San Pedro Sula | Honduras | HN | City | 15.5039 | -88.0157 | 21102 |  |  | Los Alpes, Boulevard McKay |
| 0014x000012jyoMAAQ | Ser Bhum Microbrewery |  |  |  | Micro | False | False | Brewery Membership | 2017-08-31 | Expired |  | Thimphu | Bhutan | BT |  | nan | nan |  |  |  | Hongtsho Hongtsho |